# How to autorun commands on OSX when ssh remotely?

Tags: macos, ssh, autorun

How to autorun commands on OSX when login remotely?

Is there a file, which is executed automatically when you ssh on iMac, like `.bashrc` on linux?

I tried `.bashrc`, `.login`, `/etc/profile`, nothing works.

Comment: The .bashrc file is probably not being sourced as it's a login shell. You may want to check your .bash_profile to see if it tries to source the .bashrc file once it's finished and the shell is interactive.

Comment: @Petesh, thanks. where can I find .bash_profile? I don't see it in ~/

Comment: If it's not there, then you need to create one. The default login behaviour is it first reads and executes commands from  the  file  /etc/profile, if that file exists. After reading that file, it looks for ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile, in that order, and reads and executes commands from the first one that exists and is readable. and also note that: When an interactive shell that is not a login shell is started, bash reads and executes commands from ~/.bashrc, if that file exists. This may be inhibited by using  the  --norc option.

Comment: @Petesh, thanks. That did it. Do you want me to convert your comment into answer or you can do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're using a login shell the `.bashrc` file is not sourced. In this case the rules for bash are quite clear:

> The default login behaviour is it first reads and executes commands from the file `/etc/profile`, if that file exists. After reading that file, it looks for `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, and `~/.profile`, in that order, and reads and executes commands from the first one that exists and is readable.

Also note that: When an interactive shell that is **not** a login shell is started, bash reads and executes commands from `~/.bashrc`, if that file exists. This may be inhibited by using the `--norc` option.